# Dual citizenship and Schengen 90/180 rule

Tags: dual-nationality, 90-180-visa-rules

I have both a US and an Italian passport, and I currently reside in the US.

A couple of questions:

- Will the 90/180 rule still apply in my situation?
- What passport should I show when I enter/leave Italy? Both?
- My understanding is that one should always show the US passport when leaving/entering the US, even if one has 2 passports. Correct?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not really a duplicate but closely related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66312/90-day-schengen-rule-when-entering-with-non-european-passport-but-having-a-sche?rq=1 There are several more questions which will tell you more, search on schengen and dual citizen to find them.

Comment: You _can_ show both passports (both in the EU and in the US), but there's not usually much point in doing so. EU officers will mostly ignore the US one, and US officers will mostly ignore the EU one.

Comment: I am not well versed in the intricacies of border control, but I would automatically assume that entering a region using a passport specifically issued from that region (enter US on a US passport, enter Schengen / EU on a Schengen / EU passport) will most of the time lead to the least amount of hassle. Exceptions could include things like regime changes and stuff, but that's not an issue here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In addition to the answer by [Ozzy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179317/dual-citizenship-and-schengen-90-180-rule/179318#179318), you **can** travel to the EU on your US passport. Getting an entry stamp on your US passport, without exit stamp within 90 days, would create the *false impression* that you did overstay. Such a *false impression* could be corrected by showing your Italian passport, so not much harm would be done.

But it is **better** to avoid this hassle altogether and to show the right passport at each border, as suggested by Ozzy.

Comment: "better to avoid this hassle altogether": if not for your own convenience then perhaps as a courtesy to the passport inspector and to the travelers waiting behind you.

Comment: This answer will only apply while ETIAS is not in force, because it will require a EU/EEA/EFTA/CH passport if you are a citizen of such country

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful comments. Much appreciated. On the same token, do I need to apply for an ETIAS once available? If eligible, I guess it wouldn't hurt given that I am also carrying a US passport. Thanks again.

Comment: @Maurizio, you should not need it if you enter on your Italian passport. Which of course requires that passport to be available. I don't know if they will even issue one unless you conceal your Italian citizenship.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella there does not appear to be any plan to prevent EU citizens from obtaining and using ETIAS authorization with a non-EU passport.  I saw a statement that EU citizens would no longer be able to use non-EU passports to travel to the EU, but it was removed fairly soon after I saw it, so I assume that they decided that this would be overly restrictive.

Comment: @o.m. do you know whether they're even planning to ask about other nationalities?

Comment: @phoog, they plan to ask about nationality. I understood that as asking about *all* nationalities, but you're right, that might be leaping to conclusions.

Answer (score 26):

You are correct. Use your US passport when arriving in the US. When arriving in ANY EU country, Italy included, you should enter AND exit passport control with your Italian passport.

Since you are an EU national, the 90 days within 180 period does not apply to you.

Answer (score 5):

As a citizen of the EU, you are not subject to the 90/180 rule. You can stay in any EU country for up to 90 days with no formailities. You can stay longer, but there may be formalities and you may need health insurance. There may also be tax implications if you spend a lot of time in a country.

Regarding passports, in general best practice is.

1. When dealing with the authorities of an EU country show them your Italian passport, when dealing with the US authorities show them your US passport.
2. When dealing with the airline or their agents show them the passport for the country you are travelling to.

Comment: not just best practice, many countries (including the US and possibly EU countries as well) require you to enter on your passport for that country if you are a citizen.